# DirectX 2D Sprite Texture

Tags: directx, 2d, sprite, textures

Im trying to make directx display a sprite from a sprite sheet I found on the internet but it doesn't seem to be displaying the texture in the correct position as im specifying it.

```
    D3DXVECTOR2 scaling = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0,1.0);
D3DXVECTOR2 center = D3DXVECTOR2(64,64);
D3DXMatrixTransformation2D(&mat,NULL,0.0,&scaling,NULL,rot,&position);
sprite->SetTransform(&mat);
sprite->Draw(zombieTexture,&srcRect,NULL,NULL,0xFFFFFFFF);
```

srcRect is defined as follows:
    srcRect.top = 384;
    srcRect.bottom = 512;
    srcRect.left = 512;
    srcRect.right = 640;

which should give the part of the texture like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HxfL.png

But instead im getting this https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Q9w.png (ignore the rotation)

What am I doing wrong?